# How can I use the VPN connection of my client VM?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

My Cisco VPN client doesn't support my 64-bit Win7 machine. As a workaround, I am running the client inside a VM in "XP Mode". I do most of my work inside this VM.

I would really like to do all of my work in Windows 7 and only use the VM for its VPN connection. Is this possible? How do I configure it?

Comment: I was looking for this, too a while back.  They say ShrewSoft VPN works, http://serverfault.com/questions/5221/64-bit-cisco-vpn-client-ipsec.  Never figured out how to configure it, though that's on the backburner.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new route covering the network on the other side of the VPN whose gateway is the address of the guest as seen from the host.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Beyond `route add`? Not really. You haven't provided enough details about your network config and your eventual goal.